# php not processing or reading my json data from postman and my c++ app

Tags: php, node.js, json

`{"example":"123456"}` is what am trying to send from postman to my server-side code since my c++ app is working fine with 1 of my Node.js projects.

This is what am doing atm I have been trying since 4 hours now even more but couldn't get it to work tried so many things.

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $obj = json_decode($json); print ($obj['example']); ?>
```

Comment: Please provide a var_dump of $json

Comment: $ php -r "var_dump(json_decode('{\"example\":\"123456\"}'));" does the job, I think $json is the problème and does not contain what you think it contains

Comment: `json_decode($json);` will decode it as an object - so `print ($obj->example);`, check using `print_r($obj);`

Comment: Use the json_last_error() function to determine if an error occurred during decoding.

Comment: nvm guys i moved to something else not json something much more simple but thank you all for trying to help!